# Data.table: "group counter" based on either a given column OR another column

Tags: r, data.table

I have this `data.table`:

```
> DT <- data.table(x = c(15,48,NA,NA,NA,45,45,45,45,75,75,75,NA,2,3,1), y = c(74,159,120,120,120,14,14,14,14,12,23,23,8,8,8,8))
> DT
     x   y
 1: 15  74
 2: 48 159
 3: NA 120
 4: NA 120
 5: NA 120
 6: 45  14
 7: 45  14
 8: 45  14
 9: 45  14
10: 75  12
11: 75  23
12: 75  23
13: NA   8
14:  2   8
15:  3   8
16:  1   8
```

I would like to create a column of "group counter" based on either the column "x" OR the column "y". I tested: `DT[ , Index := .GRP, by = c("x","y") ]`. But, I don't obtain the desired result which must be:

```
    > DT
     x   y Index
 1: 15  74     1
 2: 48 159     2
 3: NA 120     3
 4: NA 120     3
 5: NA 120     3
 6: 45  14     4
 7: 45  14     4
 8: 45  14     4
 9: 45  14     4
10: 75  12     5
11: 75  23     5
12: 75  23     5
13: NA   8     6
14:  2   8     6
15:  3   8     6
16:  1   8     6
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you want NAs to be treated. If there was an extra line `17: NA 8`, would you give it index 6 or 7?

Comment: The result will be index 6 (i.e., `17: NA 8 6`).

Comment: I think you're saying two consecutive rows should be in the same group if, and only if, *either* the two xs are the same or the two ys are the same. I guess I'm trying to ask if `NA` is special here. If two consecutive xs are both `NA`, does that count as being the same? I guess an example of this would be changing the `120` to `121` in row `4:`, would that change the grouping?

Comment: Yes, the group would change if 4: NA 121. I don't have rows with both  NA for the columns x and y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is method using `cumsum` with some conditions:

```
DT[, cumsum(c(1, tail(pmin(x!=shift(x), y!=shift(y),na.rm=TRUE), -1)))]
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

The `x != shift(x)` compares adjacent elements in the column (same with y) and returns a logical. The `pmin` function compares the results of the logical comparison and chooses the minimum of each element, ie if either vector has an element that did not change, then the observation is marked as not changing.  The `tail` function drops the initial NA, and the `cumsum` function adds up the results into the desired vector.

Note that this method will produce NAs where both observations of x and y have NAs. You could fix this in an additional step, before using `cumsum`.

---

This will work on character variables:

```
# same data.table with character variables
DT <- data.table(x = as.character(c(15,48,NA,NA,NA,45,45,45,45,75,75,75,NA,2,3,1)),
                 y = as.character(c(74,159,120,120,120,14,14,14,14,12,23,23,8,8,8,8)))

DT[, cumsum(c(1, tail(pmin(x!=shift(x), y!=shift(y),na.rm=TRUE), -1)))]
 [1] 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Note that unlike `data.frame`, `data.table` does not convert character variables to to factors:

```
str(DT)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  16 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: chr  "15" "48" NA NA ...
 $ y: chr  "74" "159" "120" "120" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Yup just saw that. I guess `c(1, tail(x, -1))` could alternately be written as `replace(x, 1, 1)`

Comment: Is there an efficiency argument for `replace` versus `c(1, tail)`, or just that it reads better? I remember testing `replace` when I saw akrun using it and found that it made copies.

Comment: Nope, no argument, possibly preferable for readability is all.

Comment: Thank you very much Imo for your answer. The code is very useful for the numeric variables. Is it possible to do this when the columns "x" and "y" are character variables ?

Comment: @Nell If you try this with character variables, I think it should work since the vars are only used for equality testing (the `!=`).

Comment: @Nell this works with character variables: see my updated answer. In fact, it will work with one character variable and one numeric variable as well.

Comment: I am testing with numeric and character variables but I obtain this error message: `Error in tail(pmin(x != shift(x), y != shift(y), na.rm = TRUE), -1) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'tail': Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shift’ for signature ‘"character"’` or `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shift’ for signature ‘"numeric"’`

Comment: It works for the example data if I remove `as.character` from the `data.table` function that I posted in the second part. Does this work for you or do you get the same error?

Comment: In fact, the function `shift` exists in several packages. So, I used the function `detach(package, unload=TRUE)`. Now, this works !!! Thank you very much Imo for the code.